# PHP how to strip a url

Tags: php

i want to strip a url with PHP but i can't figure out how to do it.
I thought about explode() but the problem is, what parameter can i use?
Because i need to have every single piece of the url to use it later on in the 
script.

I specificaly need this parts splitted:

1. http:// or https://
2. www.thewebsite.com/all_the_folowing_parameters

And it also needs to work when www. is missing.

Example:

http://www.thiswebsite.com/thispage.php?this=parameter&thisis_anotherone

Then i thought i could count the characters of the url, but it could also be https, so then my plan failed.

Can anyone give me some advice? It looks that easy, but i just can't figure it out..

Comment: Did u try preg_split

Comment: there is everything in the `$_SERVER` variable if it is comes from web.

Comment: Use explode() function to split the characters

Comment: u can use explode hope this link will help u [Get full URL in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6768793/get-the-full-url-in-php)

Answer (score 3):

use [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.parse-url.php)

```
print_r(parse_url('http://www.thiswebsite.com/thispage.php?this=parameter&thisis_anotherone'));

Array ( [scheme] => http [host] => www.thiswebsite.com [path] => /thispage.php [query] => this=parameter&thisis_anotherone )
```

Answer (score 0):

Another, less efficient way

```
if(substr($url, 0, 5) == "https"){
    $part1 = "https://";
    $part2 = substr($url, 8); }
else {
    $part1 = "http://";
    $part2 = substr($url, 7); }
```